# How do I hide options within a range of selects based upon changes in different select?

Tags: javascript

Related [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/donnieg/eb57opkL/3/)

```
<form id="calendar_form">
    <div class="day1">
        Day 1
        <table class="selector_table">
            <select name="select1">
                <option></option>
                <option value="optionA">PersonA</option>
                <option value="optionB">PersonB</option>
            </select>
            <select name="select2">
                <option></option>
                <option value="optionA">PersonA</option>
                <option value="optionB">PersonB</option>
            </select>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="day2">
        Day 2
        <table class="selector_table">
            <select name="select3">
                <option></option>
                <option value="optionA">PersonA</option>
                <option value="optionB">PersonB</option>
            </select>
            <select name="select4">
                <option></option>
                <option value="optionA">PersonA</option>
                <option value="optionB">PersonB</option>
            </select>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $("select").change(function(){
        var selectThatWasChanged = $(this).attr('id');
        var valueToRemove = $(this).val();
        var dayWorkingWith = $(this).closest('.selector_table');
        $('option', dayWorkingWith).not('#' + selectThatWasChanged + ' option');
        $('option[value="' + valueToRemove + '"]').not('#' + selectThatWasChanged + ' option').hide();
    });
</script>
```

I've been playing with this for an hour, and I'm frustrated. sigh. What I'm trying to accomplish is this: If PersonA is selected in Day1, he should not be available to pick again anywhere in Day1. However, PersonA should still be available on Day2.

Currently if PersonA is selected, PersonA is removed from all other selects. I tried to hone in on just the relevant selects by using the closest('.selector_table').

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much, in advance!

Bonus basic question: would it be tremendously more work to "undo" the change. For instance, if someone selects PersonA it hides PersonA as described, but then if PersonB is selected thereafter on the same select, it undoes that change and PersonA becomes available again?

Answer (score 2):

Apply `change` event to the select Element, get the sibling `select` and disable it's matching `option element`.

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  const selectedOptionVal = $(this).find(":selected")[0].value;
  const sibSelectEle = $(this).siblings('select');
  sibSelectEle.children('option').each(function(_, option) {
    if (selectedOptionVal == option.value) {
      $(option).attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $(option).attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calendar_form">
  <div class="day1">
    Day 1
    <table class="selector_table">
      <select name="select1">
        <option></option>
        <option value="optionA">PersonA</option>
        <option value="optionB">PersonB</option>
      </select>
      <select name="select2">
        <option></option>
        <option value="optionA">PersonA</option>
        <option value="optionB">PersonB</option>
      </select>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="day2">
    Day 2
    <table class="selector_table">
      <select name="select3">
        <option></option>
        <option value="optionA">PersonA</option>
        <option value="optionB">PersonB</option>
      </select>
      <select name="select4">
        <option></option>
        <option value="optionA">PersonA</option>
        <option value="optionB">PersonB</option>
      </select>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```